# 2 scroll bars present in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm having a bit of annoyance. I want a scroll bar present in my flutter web 'page' at all times, to indicate to the user that there's still some elements to view them. And I achieved this using scrollbar isAlwaysShown to true in my Theme class.

Now, when I use GridView.builder to generate elements on the screen, I must provide height constraints beforehand, or else I'll get an error that says 'height is infinite'.

The problem with this is, there are 2 scroll bars visible at all times. One from the SingleChildScrollView, and one from the GridView.builder. I need the SingleChildScrollView with the column so I can have a footer at the bottom of the page.

My question is, how can I get rid of the GridView.builder scroll bar?

Thanks in advance...

My code:

```
Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: _size.height),
              margin: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
              ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10)
              : null,
              padding: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
              ? desktopPadding
              : smallAndMediumPadding,
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
                itemCount: 12,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return GridCard(name: '', image: '');
                }
              )
            ),
            /////////////// Footer ///////////////////
            Footer()
          ]
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: Having a scroll inside a scroll will confuse and frustrate users in terms of UX regardless of how many scroll bars are visible. I'd recommend trying to put the footer at the bottom of the grid as it's own element so you only have one scroll

Comment: To put the footer at the bottom, one have to use Column or ListView. Or, use bottomNavigationBar option in the Scaffold (which is wrong, as it will be persistent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can remove the `BoxConstraints` from your **Container** and to solve the `height` issue you have a property in **GridView.builder** named `shrinkWrap`. You just need to set it `true` and it will solve your height issue.

```
shrinkWrap: true,
```

and after that you may have issue with `Scrolling` the **GridView.builder** so to solve that use another property `primary` and set it to `false`

```
primary : false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use multiple Scrollables inside each other to get footer functionality. By using `shrinkWrap` on the inner scrollable (`GridView`) you'd effectively turn it into a regular unscrollable widget and use scrolling of the outer view (`SingleChildScrollView`). It is terrible for performance because Flutter would have to build, layout and (probably) render entire `GridView` including all the items every time.

You should instead use `CustomScrollView` to display your grid and footer like this:

```
Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverPadding(
          // not sure what you were trying to do with your padding
          padding: (Responsive.isDesktop(context)
                  ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10)
                  : EdgeInsets.zero) +
              (Responsive.isDesktop(context)
                  ? desktopPadding
                  : smallAndMediumPadding),
          sliver: SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
            ),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => GridCard(name: '', image: ''),
              childCount: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Footer(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```